# Get text from menu or highlighted menu -powershell or python

Tags: python, powershell, automation

I am doing some automation on this application where I am using wshell keys to use keystrokes to automate what I want with the app. However, I am stuck at a point where I need to pick a specific sheet/view/section. I see a menu that has a list of the specific names so I can use variables to match what view/sheet/section I want to get to **but I don't know how to get the list of text from the window menu so I can do do some calculation with it. **

Any ideas that involve python or powershell are welcome. I will keep updating this question with stuff I have tried as I research. I would have tried something like selenium but that only seems to work for webapps.

[image]

Comment: Would this always be a Windows Application?

Comment: yes 100% always a windows app @Start-Automating